# Minecraft Morph Mod T-pose

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-mods

So I want to use Morph mod 1.7.10 in my modpack. I'm using the latest 1.7.10 versions of both Morph mod and IchunUtil. When I morph into any mob, it always faces the same direction, no matter what mob it is, and is in a static, T-pose like position.[image: The Skeleton is me]

so I was wondering if there could be any incompatibilities with the mod that are causing this, or maybe some setting in the game/mod is causing this. If there is a fix that anyone knows of, that would be greatly appreciated.

the mods list is shown at the timestamped part of the video:

Comment: Are you sure you linked the correct video? It doesn't look like Minecraft at all.

Comment: did you actually play the video?

Comment: No, I just saw the title and thumbnail and lost any and all will to click on it.

Comment: after further experimentation, it would appear that the issue comes from one of these mods: https://i.imgur.com/zvRDba5.png

Comment: That's a good start, now try removing more and see if it still happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after extensive trial and error, I discovered that the mod "Galaxy Space" was messing around with the properties of mob models. I changed the mod to a different version, and that seemed to fix the issue.